# jQuery pass specific div ID

Tags: jquery

How do I do this?  I have a function which is passed the ID of a link.  I need to write my function something like:

```
function areYouSure(id){
$('.sure' + id).html('blah blah blah');
}
```

The div is called "sure".  How do I pass in the ID to the jquery object?  This doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of a few of the DIVs for clarification

Comment: u have div element is set to class with different id, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The . is for class accessor use #

like this:

```
function areYouSure(id){
$('#' + id).html('blah blah blah');
}
```

if you have all elements with class="sure" inside a `<div>` element with different id then do it like this:

```
function areYouSure(id){
$('div#'+ id + '.sure').html('blah blah blah');
}
```

Comment: The div being passed has a class not an id since there are multiple divs with the same name but different IDs

Comment: at a time you are saying it has ID then at the same time you are saying It doesn't have ID...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function areYouSure(id){
  $('#' + id).html('blah blah blah');
}
```

Since you are passing the id, you can just look up that element via that id.